# How does one include a module with cache expirations in sweepers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, observer-pattern, sweeper

We have the following sweeper in a rails application:

```
class AgencyEquipmentTypeSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper 
  observe AgencyEquipmentType

  #include ExpireOptions
  def after_update(agency_equipment_type)
    expire_options(agency_equipment_type)
  end

  def after_delete(agency_equipment_type)
    expire_options(agency_equipment_type)
  end

  def after_create(agency_equipment_type)
    expire_options(agency_equipment_type)
  end

  def expire_options(agency_equipment_type)
    Rails.cache.delete("agency_equipment_type_options/#{agency_equipment_type.agency_id}")
  end
end
```

We'd like to extract the after_update, after_delete, and after_create callbacks to a module called "ExpireOptions"

The module *should* look like this (with the 'expire_options' method staying behind in the
original sweeper):

```
module ExpireOptions
  def after_update(record)
    expire_options(record)
  end

  def after_delete(record)
    expire_options(record)
  end

  def after_create(record)
    expire_options(record)
  end
end

class AgencyEquipmentTypeSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper 
  observe AgencyEquipmentType

  include ExpireOptions

  def expire_options(agency_equipment_type)
    Rails.cache.delete("agency_equipment_type_options/#{agency_equipment_type.agency_id}")
  end
end
```

BUT the cache expirations only work if we define the methods explicitly inside the sweeper. Is there an easy way to extract those callback methods to a module, and still have them work?

Comment: That's very odd. Both examples work locally for me. What are you using for your cache store?

Comment: it should work with your current code. no changes needed. include statement takes care of everything.

Comment: Do the module based methods after_create, etc. get called at all?

Comment: Seconded that the code works locally here - is anything not mentioned configured in any exceptionally non-standard ways? More code via a bin link?

Comment: Darn. Once I used memcached -vvv, I saw that it was in fact caching as expected. %#*%@#*$^#(@...there goes 300 points I'll never get back.

Comment: @lakshman or @Jack Chu, If you'd like to formalize your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to award you the 300 points.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
module ExpireOptions
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      after_update :custom_after_update
      after_delete :custom_after_delete
      after_create :custom_after_create
    end
  end

  def custom_after_update(record)
    expire_options(record)
  end

  def custom_after_delete(record)
    expire_options(record)
  end

  def custom_after_create(record)
    expire_options(record)
  end
end
```

Comment: I get this: `included': undefined method `after_update' for AgencyEquipmentTypeSweeper:Class

Comment: Which version of Ror are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
module ExpireOptions
  def after_update(record)
    self.send(:expire_options, record)
  end

  def after_delete(record)
    self.send(:expire_options, record)
  end

  def after_create(record)
    self.send(:expire_options, record)
  end
end
```

This should make sure it does not try to call those methods on the module, but on `self` which would hopefully be the calling object.

Does that help?